# Mesh vertices not scaling in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I started with modelling a tree and suddenly I am unable to scale vertices in edit mode for the branches mesh to go thinner or thicker. When I hit S to scale nothing happens. I don't know what suddenly went wrong. Please help 
[image: Pressing S on the keyboard to scale]

Answer (score 2):

To scale the radius for the skin modifier you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, not simply <kbd>S</kbd>.

There are also two fields in the properties panel, one for the X and one for the Y radius, "scaling" the radius with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> does the same as changing these values.
[image: properties panel]